# transform the code from using for loop to solving with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have to find which schedules(row indices) don't have the same element value consecutively even once.

```
import numpy as np
generator = np.random.default_rng(999)
schedules = generator.integers(low=0, high=5, size=(1000,21))
l=[]
for i in range(len(schedules)):
    k = 0
    for j in range(1,21):
        if schedules[i,j]-schedules[i,(j-1)]==0:
            k=k+1

    if k==0:
        l.append(i)
print(l)
```

Comment: `np.all(schedules[:, :-1] != schedules[:, 1:], 1).nonzero()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.diff` + `all` with `axis=1` to achieve this efficiently in a vectorized manner:

```
>>> np.arange(1000)[(np.diff(schedules, axis=1) != 0).all(axis=1)]
array([ 25, 138, 188, 289, 375, 426, 533, 886, 975, 982])

>>> (_ == l).all()
True
```

Comment: `(np.diff(...) != 0).all(1)` maybe better.